# WordPress Posts By Date/Day?

Tags: archives, date

I want to output on the homepage the posts from the lastest 3 days.

Like this:

> 30/03/12

```
    post 1
    post 2
    post 3
```

> 29/03/12

```
    post 1
    post 2
    post 3
```

> 28/03/12

```
    post 1
    post 2
    post 3
```

I tried:

> On 30/03/12 I have 5 posts
>
> On 29/03/12 I have 4 posts
>
> On 28/03/12 I have 3 posts

So the 3rd day is missing now 2 posts.

Also I want to use this on the archive page.

3 days a page.

On page 2 the next 3 days.

Here is my loops file

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="entry-box">
<?php $embed = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tj_video_embed', TRUE); ?>
<?php if($embed && (get_option('videoplus_fancybox_enable') == 'on')){
    $embed_url = '';
    $mode = '~http://[\d\w\s:/.]*~iS';
    preg_match($mode,$embed,$embed_url);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $embed_url[0];?>" rel="bookmark" class="various fancybox.iframe">
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php } ?>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('entry-thumb', array('class' => 'entry-thumb')); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $img_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tj_video_img_url', TRUE); ?>
        <?php if($img_url != null) { ?><img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="entry-thumb"/><?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if($embed) { ?>
        <div class="video-flag"></div>
    <?php }?>
</a>
<div class="entry-meta">
    <?php the_time('M j, Y'); ?> &middot; by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
    <span class="entry-comment">
        <?php comments_popup_link( __( '0', 'theme junkie' ), __( '1', 'theme junkie' ), __( '%', 'theme junkie' ) ); ?>
    </span>
</div><!-- .entry-meta -->
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<div class="entry-content">
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
</div><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> .entry-box -->
```

Comment: Where are you excluding posts based on dates?

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad idea for display of a blog home page and I would be interested in what you came up with, but thinking through the idea for implementation beyond the first page would be problematic:

**Pagination** - If it is just the blog home then you can easily set an offset for starting on page 2, but if each page has a variable number of posts on it (could be one, could be 20 in the past 3 days?)

**Archive home** - Archives cover a lot of areas including tags, categories, date archives and others. I am not sure that this display would work for anything but the home page of each of these.

Comment: +1 for pagination issues. Variable amount of posts per page (and case of _zero_ posts in page) would be complicated to neatly implement and possibly prohibitively expensive to compute.